# typescript union types does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two type object, one has `surename` other one does not. The error I'm getting is `Property 'surename' does not exist on type 'one | two'.` On line 26 `return <div>{el.surename}</div>`.

So looks like i can't use it like that, so if i have a component and then i want to use that component to render both types or by pressing `CTRL + SPACE` to see the available types, how can this be done, or would i have to use something like `Generic` ?

```
type one = {
  name?: string
  surename?: string
}

type two = {
  name?: string
}

// interface one {
//   name?: string
//   surename?: string
// }
// interface two {
//   name?: string
// }

type main = two[] | one[]

const data: main = [{ name: '1' }, { name: '2' }]

export const TypeScript = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((el) => {
        return <div>{el.surename}</div>
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The error simply tells that `surname` cannot be used in the union type because it doesn't exists in **all** parts. If the object is a `one`, no problem, but if it happens to be a `two`, the property won't exists. When using an union type directly you can only access properties common to all parts of the union, here only the `name`.

Comment: thank you, eh shame thought TS was able to handle this :(

Comment: It is able, it handles by giving the error :D. As it can fail depending on the actual type, you need a type assertion to ensure you have a `one` and not a `two`, and act accordingly in such case.

Comment: im having this same issue but, the point is i want to be able to accept elements whether they have  distinct field only present in one type, my function is checking if that field exists before doing something with it, why is typescript forcing me to have it on both types, what is the point of a union in this case?